# script to return info from /proc/

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to write a script that will return info from the /proc/cpuinfo, /proc/meminfo and /proc/version files.

From the cpuinfo file, I want to return the cpu Mhz and model name.
I can get these via these commands

```
    more /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | head -n 1

    more /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"
```

for the meminfo file, I want to get total memory, memory free and total used.  I can get the first 2 via these commands:

```
    more /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
    more /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree
```

and I can get the linux version # with this:

```
    more /proc/version
```

I can then have this saved as a file via redirecting the first output into a file and then append the next info items with using a >> instead of >.

My problem is this - how do I write a script that will take the info from the above and place it into this format:

```
  /proc/cpuinfo, Model name: (result of first command above)
  /proc/cpuinfo, cpu Mhz:  (result of 2nd)
  /proc/meminfo, MemTotal: (result of 3rd)
  /proc/meminfo, MemFree: (result of 4th)
  /proc/meminfo, MemUsed:  (calculate it based off memtotal and memfree)
  /proc/version, Linux version #:
```

I know how to use cut, awk and more, etc but do not know how to set this up.  I do not know how to force the calculation of the mem used either.

Any help you can give would be appreciated.

EDIT:  I use the more because I am not too familiar with Linux.

I am getting closer and closer to what I want to do with a combination of what is posted here and what I need to come up with.

MATH function - 
I just want to take the memtotal and subtract memfree from it.

Could I just create a variable such as

```
    memused=$(bc $memtotal - memfree)
```

and then echo it out?

Comment: Post sample input and expected output. Personally I've no idea what those files can contain but I know a bit about awk and may be able to help.

Comment: Are you familiar with Python? If yes, my article here: http://amitsaha.github.io/site/notes/articles/python_linux/article.html may be of help.

Comment: There is absolutely zero reason to pipe `more` to grep.  Useless use of cat is bad enough, but this is a useless use of more!  Just do `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo`

Answer (score 1):

With a simple shell function like:

```
filedata() {
    grep -H "$@" | sed -e 's/:/, /'
}
```

You can get most of the data you need by calling

```
filedata 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo
filedata -E 'Mem(Total|Free)' /proc/meminfo
filedata . /proc/version
```

To get MemUsed you could use something like:

```
awk '/MemFree/ {free=$2} /MemTotal/ {total=$2} END {print FILENAME",","MemUsed:", total-free}' /proc/meminfo
```

Alternatively the following awk script will do it all for you (though not in exactly the order of your example output):

```
awk '/model name|cpu MHz|MemTotal|MemFree|^Linux/ {
    print FILENAME",",$0
}

/MemTotal|MemFree/ {
    v=$1
    gsub(/^Mem/, "", v)
    gsub(/:$/, "", v)
    mem[v]=$2
}

END {
    print "/proc/meminfo, MemUsed:", mem["Total"] - mem["Free"]
}' /proc/cpuinfo /proc/meminfo /proc/version
```

Comment: I was trying not to be too overwhelming all at once. So the first bit was keeping the same "flavor" of operation and the awk answer was "but you really don't need to do that much work for this".

Answer (score 1):

In a simplified way you can do the following:

**EXAMPLE**

```
#!/bin/sh

LOCATION=$1

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]
then
echo "Usage: ./$0 <FILE>"
else
model=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -m 1 "model name"|cut -d' ' -f 4-);
mhz=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -m 1 "cpu MHz"|cut -d' ' -f 3-);
mem=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal|cut -d' ' -f 2-);
free=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree|cut -d' ' -f 2-);
ver=$(cat /proc/version|cut -d' ' -f 3);


fi


echo -e \
"/proc/cpuinfo, Model Name: $model
/proc/cpuinfo, CPU MHz: $mhz
/proc/meminfo, MemTotal: $mem 
/proc/meminfo, MemFree: $free 
/proc/version, Linux Verion #: $ver" > $LOCATION
```

That will place each result in a variable so you can `echo` it into a file that you declare when you call the script like `sh test.sh mynewfile.txt`.

As for "I do not know how to force the calculation of the mem used either." please update you question to include how you expect those values to be present (kb, MB, GB) and a sample output you are looking for.

Comment: You might want to lose the [useless `cat`s](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: @tripleee the cat is not useless persay.For someone who is not comfortable in the *nix shells it provides a level of verbosity which is important in helping the OP understand what is happening with the command. Without it reading it as you would the English language (left to right) the command would make less sense and be harder to understand.

Comment: I want to use whatever # comes from the MemTotal and MemFree.  Would something like this work: memused=$(MemTotal-MemFree)???

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get value using `awk` only:

```
model=$(awk -F: '/model name/ {print $2;exit}' /proc/cpuinfo)
mhz=$(awk -F: '/cpu MHz/ {print $2;exit}' /proc/cpuinfo)
mem=$(awk -F"[: ]+" '/MemTotal/ {print $2;exit}' /proc/meminfo)
etc
```